# Archive oldest date modified folder and move to another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, archive, zip

I am trying to archive the oldest date modified folder and move to another folder.

My folder structure is currently c:\test\test1 (latest folder) and c:\test\test2 and c:\test\test3

I would like to zip test2 and test 3 as they are oldest modified folders and move them to another location i.e c:\archive

I have managed to get it working to zip the oldest folder but it does not move it and also does not move to another folder location which I would like it to keep my archive tidy.

Also a nice to have would be to have the zipfolder with archive_date.zip

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile

files_dir = r'c:\test\' # here should be path to directory with your files
files = glob.glob(files_dir + '\*')
# find all files that located in specified directory
files_modify_dt = [os.path.getmtime(file) for file in files]
# take files except last modified file
files_to_zip = [file for _, file in sorted(zip(files_modify_dt, files))][:-1]
# zip of selected files
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(files_dir, 'archive.zip'), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_obj:
    for file in files_to_zip:
        zip_obj.write(file, os.path.basename(file))
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Check out [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

Comment: Good suggestion, have tried but still not getting the result i am after.